# Jquery Mobile Auto adding icon to class

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I have bit of a weird problem. I use php to generate the html code I need to create a list view. I do this twice with different sql, first only returns rows from future, second returns everything.

On the home page I use the below code:

```
                while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
                    $output .= "\t\t<li class=\"ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow\"><a href=\"workoutSpecific.php?workoutId=$workoutID\" style=\"text-decoration: none; color:inherit;\" >";
                    $output .= "\t\t<div class=\"bi-list-item-primary\">$title</div>";
                    $output .= "\t\t<div class=\"bi-list-item-secondary\">";
                    $output .= "\t\t<p>$date  at  $time</p>";
                    $output .= "\t\t</a></li>";
                }
```

This produced the code as follows, note the first `<a>` DOESN'T have any class elements or icons.

```
 <div id="upcomingWorkouts">
  <h3>Upcoming Workouts:</h3>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="allWorkouts" data-theme="b">
<li class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
    <a href="workoutSpecific.php?workoutId=5" style="text-decoration: none; color:inherit;">
        <div class="bi-list-item-primary">Back</div>
    </a>
    <div class="bi-list-item-secondary">
        <a href="workoutSpecific.php?workoutId=5" style="text-decoration: none; color:inherit;">
            <p>Sat 16th Jan 2016 at 10:10AM</p>
        </a>
    </div>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

now on my other page, its generated the exact same way but it has a class with a carat icon in it.....

```
<li class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
    <a href="workoutSpecific.php?workoutId=5" style="text-decoration: none; color:inherit;" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">
        <div class="bi-list-item-primary">Back</div>
    </a>
    <div class="bi-list-item-secondary">
        <a href="workoutSpecific.php?workoutId=5" style="text-decoration: none; color:inherit;">
            <p>Sat 16th Jan 2016 at 10:10AM</p>
        </a>
    </div>
</li>
```

Sorry this is bit of a hard one to explain, but does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: can you provide the code of the parent eleemt. My guess is that the second one is inside of a `<ul data-role="listview">`

Comment: I've amended the code above to show these, they are both in the same divID and listview (different ID's)

Answer (score 0):

Just add data-role="none" on your element and JQM ignore this